# MySQL Index for searching for NULL values in text fields

Tags: mysql, index, blob

I need to do the simple query `SELECT id FROM table WHERE blob_field IS NULL`.

`blob_field` is a longblob. If I create an index on `blob_field` with prefix length 1, will this be sufficient to use for this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a prefix length of one will allow you to have a working index for looking up NULLs.

Here's the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12bf3/1/0

The EXPLAIN says that it is using the desired index.

Of course you might want to try a larger test to make sure it performs as well in reality as you hope.

Comment: Any idea why a length of 0 is not allowed? Given that the 'nullness' takes up actual space and is actually useful, it seems perfectly viable.

Comment: At least for MySQL 8.0.15 the query: `SELECT COUNT(1) from table where field is null` take ages (got ~4M rows) if I am using `INDEX(field(1))` whilst when I am using full length the reponse is immediate. Surprisingly in both cases `EXPLAIN` for both cases is exactly the same, index is used, same number of rows, 100% filtered etc.
This is really surprising. Looking for a ways to improve, I don't want to waste that much space to index full value, just to search ON NULL or not.
Perhaps I could use generated column `STORED` which I could index.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do like this :

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob_field ) FROM table WHERE predicate ;
```

Comment: Why would that be better than `SELECT id` ? To clarify, I'm asking about the best way to create an index for the `WHERE blob_field IS NULL` part.

Comment: this query will do !